# getting API response in postman but not in ionic app

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic2

laravel Controller

```
public function getbrands(Request $request)
{
     $id = DB::table('products')->where('product', '=',$request->product)->first()->id;
    $brands = Product::find($id)->brands;
      return response()->json($brands);

}
```

this is what iam getting in Postman

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "brand": "Bluemount",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": 2,
            "brand_id": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "brand": "LG",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": 2,
            "brand_id": 3
        }
    }
]
```

But iam getting error in Ionic App

```
{…}
_body: "{\"message\":\"Trying to get property of non-object\",\"status_code\":500}"
headers: Object { _headers: Map, _normalizedNames: Map }
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
type: 2
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getbrands"
__proto__: Object { constructor: Response(), toString: Response.prototype.toString() }
call.ts:143:10
Dismissed toast
```

But when i change $request->product to 'RO' in getBrands function like below

```
public function getbrands(Request $request)
{
     $id = DB::table('products')->where('product', '=','RO')->first()->id;
    $brands = Product::find($id)->brands;
      return response()->json($brands);

}
```

then i am getting data in ionic app.
plz hello where iam wrong

Comment: Open up laravel.log and see yourself where you are wrong. From data you provided only magician would correctly guess whats going on.

Comment: Yeah, you're getting a HTTP 500 error, an Internal Server Error, so check the server logs. That will give you the best clue. All the best

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your request header contains:

`Content-Type:Application/json` and `Accept: application/json`

> "Trying to get property of non-object\",\"status_code\":500

This error is happening because of `$request->product`,  `product` parameter its not being provided in the request object therefore laravel squawks. So make sure when you make the request towards the api you provide the `product` url parameter!

I am pretty sure if you add this code to your method, you will get the response: Product not provided in request!

```
public function getbrands(Request $request)
{
     if(!request()->has('product'))
     {
         return response(['message'=>'Product not provided in request'], 402);
     }

     $id = DB::table('products')->where('product', '=','RO')->first()->id;
     $brands = Product::find($id)->brands;
     return response()->json($brands);

}
```

Comment: Thanks you are right i am getting same error message message'=>'Product not provided in request'

Answer (score -2):

Whether the request data is getting there correctly or not, which it seems it is not, you have issues with how you are using results here.

You are running queries that could return empty results, `null`, in this case. You will need to check these. If an invalid `product` is sent with the request you will end up with errors because you are not checking if the results of these queries actually return anything before trying to use those results.

```
// could return a null
DB::table('products')->where('product', '=',$request->product)->first();

// also could return a null
Product::find($id);
```